# Mysqli INSERT with $_POST

Tags: php, database, insert, mysqli

I have been ripping my hair for days over this problem so any helpful advice would be appreciated. Calling the following function returns nothing. The POST values are set (They print with echo) and the database let me update and extract with other functions. What am i missing?

Oh yea, all the values are strings.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");    
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['layout'], $_POST['page_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Are the values correctly inserted in the DB ?

Comment: I assume, that page_id is an integer value, so you should probably indicate the variables like `...bind_param('ssi', ...` Am I assuming wrong?

Comment: Does `var_dump($stmt->ErrorInfo())` show anything?

Comment: Did you check that `$stmt` isn't boolean false, e.g. the prepare failed? You're not checking ANY return values, which means you're simply assuming success. Never assume success. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: bidn param should be ONE per param :)

Comment: @Brian how they are 4?

Comment: He's not using PDO... although he tagged it that way. probably an honest mistake... This is MySQLi. At least it looks exactly like it

Comment: nobody realized it's actually `bindParam()`? XDD

Comment: -1 for confusing question

Comment: All the values are strings? So in your database, page_id is a varchar or an integer?

Comment: you re right it's mysqli, then bind_param is ok, and my answer wrong xD then it's because he is actually binding 4 params

Comment: No, he's binding 3 params. The first parameter of `bind_param` is to identify the datatype. `sss` stands for `string string string`... So he's adding 3 strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    die($db->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['name'], $_POST['layout'], $_POST['page_id']);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die($stmt->error);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Or, if, as you said, all your values are strings (given, they are as well defined as varchars/something similar in your database), you can still `bind_param("sss"...`

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful answer, after adding the error reporting it turned out that my problem was with the database. I will use error reports more frequently in the future!

Comment: @ViktorBurström this is quite outdated way of error reporting, and surely **insecure** one. Just a friendly warning.

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you explain why? Would be interesting for me aswell :) I stopped using MySQLi quite a while ago, so my knowledge about it is surely outdated

Comment: It is not a matter of mysqli, but rather of security basics. An error message, thrown right into hands of a potential hacker on a live site is a sure christmas present for him.

Comment: You're right. I actually just wanted him to get a MySQL error output to check his database, not use this as his ultimate solution. Should've mentioned that. In this case your answer is the proper one. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

At glance, there is nothing wrong with this code (in case you are indeed using mysqli). So, the **only** way to get to know what is going wrong is to get the **error message.**

Add this line before connect

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

and make sure you can see PHP errors

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @DanFromGermany actually the question was "What am I missing"... he's missing error reporting :)

Comment: Everything in the question is Mysqli

Answer (score -1):

Aren't **page_id**'s **integers** ? Since the asker first tagged the question as **PDO**, here is the **PDO** version :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES (:name,:layout,:pid)");
$sth->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':layout', $_POST['layout'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':pid', $_POST['page_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or (MySQLi):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['name'], $_POST['layout'], $_POST['page_id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or (PDO) :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['name'], $_POST['layout'], $_POST['page_id']));
```

Comment: Why do you leave out the bind_param function? that wasn't wrong

Comment: sss = string string string

Comment: I dont think you can use named parameters in the SQL statement like `:name` in MySQLi.. IIRC it has to be a question mark

Comment: @Subin Maybe i saw an old version of your answer, but you had named parameters first in your MySQLi part ;) I know the upper part is PDO, where you can, as I'm also aware of, use named parameters. Your lower part is MySQLi, where you cant. That's what I was referencing to. But now this version is correct.

Comment: "s" for integers works as best as "i" does. So, your version is no different from the OP. Answer a question only if you are sure of the cause.

Answer (score -5):

Here you are:

```
$name = $_POST['layout'];
$layout = $_POST['layout'];
$page_id= $_POST['page_id'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content_page (name, layout, page_id) VALUES ('".$name."','".$layout."','".$page_id."')");
```

Comment: This is the perfect example what you MUST NOT do

Comment: PDO is for escaping SQL Injection